# CSS Sibling hover states effecting each other

Tags: css, less

I have the following situation in a table that I want to solve using only CSS/LESS:

On the hover of the row indicate interaction on close icon

On the hover of done icon indicate interaction on done icon

This example is simplified to explain the problem I am having.

```
.row:hover {
  .close {
    color: red;
  }
}
.doneCell:hover {
  .done:hover {
    color: red;
  }
  & ~ .closeCell {
      .close {
        color: black;
      }
  }
}
```

What I currently have doesn't exactly do as I want, it removes interaction hover on close icon when the cell is hovered, so it when the doneCell is hovered it looks like there is not interaction. I only want the color black to apply if the .done:hover exists.

I was looking at `:not` to try solve the problem with something crazy like:

```
.closeCell:not(~ .doneCell:hover .done:not(&:hover)) {
    .close {
      color: black;
    }
}
```

but any variation of :not I am trying to use doesn't achieve what I need. I am hoping that there is something simple I am missing that someone can see.

Thanks

Here is my current attempt at it:

```css
.row:hover .close {
  color: red;
}
.doneCell:hover .done:hover {
  color: red;
}
.doneCell:hover ~ .closeCell .close {
  color: black;
}
.close,
.done {
  background-color: pink;
}
table {
  max-width: 400px;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.0/less.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell doneCell">
        <i class="material-icons done">done</i>
      </td>
      <td class="cell closeCell">
        <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
      </td>
      <td>Some data</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

https://codepen.io/sheogora/pen/VXeJwv

Comment: try with z-index, but think that when you hover the cell, you're hovering the row too. supposedly the deepest "son" is the high if it was a 3D plane. Using :not your selector only will stop working. Then, if it works as default expected, row is working only in the whitespaces between cells, and cells are targeting to itself. Add html and a working snippet if you can please.

Comment: hi @JoelBonetR, at the end of my question there is a link to a codepen of my example

Comment: @Pete sorry I added the code snippet into the question, but I couldn't get it working with hovers?

Answer (score 0):

Use an appropiate selector for the first part:

```
.row > td.closeCell:hover {
  .close {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

And add the other case:

```
.row > td.doneCell:hover {
  .done {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Now both are painted red when their own cell is on hover.

Comment: i understood that this is what you needed. if not i'm sorry. isn't it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort, but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. If you read the question again it mentions that I want the close icon to look selected when the row is hovered, however when the done icon is hovered I want to unset the row hover.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to reach? Hover is an event, you'll need to use JavaScript preventdefault to deal with...

Comment: Im asking if it is possible to not use javascript and solve the problem using only css/less. The situation I am having that I want to visually explain to the user if a hover happens on the row, the delete icon is highlighted, which means if the user clicks the row then the row will be deleted. However if the user is hovering on the done icon, then I highlight it to represent that if a user clicks the tick then the row will be added. My example is simplified so without context the following might be confusing as why I want that particular interaction between icons, but that is what I need :)

Comment: with the code i posted you: when you hover the delete icon cell, the delete icon is highlighted. But when you're out of this cell, it's not. Then if you're in the done cell, the done icon is highlighted (and the delete one is not). isn't the same that you are telling me?

Comment: No, I want any part of the row when highlighted to represent that the delete action will be performed. In my current code that is what is happening, however the problem is when you hover the done cell, none of the actions are highlighted, because the user hasn't yet hovered on the done icon. I need the general sibling selector '~' to apply only when the .done:hover is applied, instead of what it currently is doing which is applying the unset of .close when .doneCell is hovered. I am sorry I am not very good at explaining maybe.

Comment: don't worry, it's only that what you want is not logicaly from the usability point of view and would cause unwanted deletes... let me edit it.